# Specific mails for multiple users class which extended devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails 3 application and 2 user models for authentication with using devise gem.
First class named as StandartUser and second class named as AdminUser.
I can override devise controllers but i want to use specific mails for reset_password_instructions.
Just want to change mail subjects.
For StandartUser -> Mail subject should be "reset password mail"
For AdminUser -> Mail subject should be "bla bla bla bla"
How can i implement this idea on my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating the [Devise Views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) will allow you to modify what is in them. This will allow you to change the content but in order to change the subject you will have to [override the Devise mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L10) by [creating your own mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer) and having devise use it.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default :from => "notifications@example.com"

 def welcome_email(user)
   @user = user
   @url  = "http://example.com/login"
   # your code you want to change subject
   if ...
     @subject = ...
   else
     @subject = ...
   end
   mail(:to => user.email, :subject => @subject)
 end
end
```

Then in the devise config:

```
config.mailer = "MyMailer"
```

Comment: i think class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base should be class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer

Comment: If you want to override the Devise mailer itself and use the built in helper methods you could do that. Although this may be more hassle than it is worth since you only want to change the subject. Creating your own mailer allows you to skip using Devise's built in helpers to translate the resource (which you would have to format to use the devise helpers). For reference the mailer helper methods: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb Using your own mailer of course eliminates the use of devise views etc.